# error: Compilation failed: IrClassSymbolImpl is unbound. Signature: null

Tags: ios, kotlin-multiplatform

```
error: java.lang.IllegalStateException: IrClassSymbolImpl is unbound. Signature: null
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.symbols.impl.IrBindableSymbolBase.getOwner(IrPrivateSymbolBase.kt)
```

When I try to use PopupPositionProvider I am getting build time error in ios app in Kotlin multiplatform

```
@Composable
private fun rememberPopupPos(
    side: PopupSide,
    onAnchorPos: (pos: IntOffset) -> Unit
) = object : PopupPositionProvider {
    override fun calculatePosition(
        anchorBounds: IntRect,
        windowSize: IntSize,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        popupContentSize: IntSize
    ): IntOffset {
        val popupRect = placePopup(
            rect = popupContentSize.toIntRect(),
            anchor = anchorBounds.inflate(anchorBounds.minDimension / 10),
            side = side,
            dir = layoutDirection
        ).constrainOffset(windowSize.toIntRect())
        onAnchorPos(anchorBounds.center - popupRect.topLeft)
        return popupRect.topLeft
    }
}
```

Comment: You seems to be facing a compiler bug. StackOverflow is not an issue tracker, you have much more chances of solving the problem by reporting it to [compose-multiplatform](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform) and to [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues)

Answer (score 0):

I have removed @Composable and some how worked

```
@Composable // Here is the problem. 
private fun rememberPopupPos(
    side: PopupSide,
    onAnchorPos: (pos: IntOffset) -> Unit
) = object : PopupPositionProvider {
    override fun calculatePosition(
        anchorBounds: IntRect,
        windowSize: IntSize,
        layoutDirection: LayoutDirection,
        popupContentSize: IntSize
    ): IntOffset {
        val popupRect = placePopup(
            rect = popupContentSize.toIntRect(),
            anchor = anchorBounds.inflate(anchorBounds.minDimension / 10),
            side = side,
            dir = layoutDirection
        ).constrainOffset(windowSize.toIntRect())
        onAnchorPos(anchorBounds.center - popupRect.topLeft)
        return popupRect.topLeft
    }
}
```